# Evaluating contour in the form $\int_{o}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-a}}{1+x}dx $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Having this improper integral 
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-a}}{1+x}dx$$

I apply the form as such $x^{a}R(x)$ as such 
$$ \oint_{\Gamma} z^{a}R(z)dz = \frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{2\pi ia}}\sum_{poles} Res_{z=z_i}R(z)z^{a} $$

Thus, 
$$  \frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{2\pi ia}} Res_{z=-1}\ z^{-a} $$

I know $z^{a} = e^{a\log(z)} = \exp(a\log(z)\ +\ a\ Arg(z)  $

I'm stump on what do at this point. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $\;z^aR(z)\;$ . How is that even close to the real function you have in the improper integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real-values of $a$, $1>a>0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(1-e^{-i2\pi/a})\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-a}}{1+x}\,dx&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{z^{-a}}{1+z}, z=-1\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i e^{-i\pi a}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi a)}
\end{align}$$

The residue was evaluated using

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{z^{-a}}{1+z}, z=-1\right)=\lim_{z\to -1}(z+1)\frac{z^{-a}}{1+z}=e^{-i\pi a}$$

since given the branch cut along the positive real axis, $-1=e^{i\pi}$ so that $(-1)^{-a}=e^{-i\pi a}$.

Comment: Actually Dr., this is perfect. Thank you, this really helped.

Comment: Pleased to hear.  You're welcome. My pleasure.  - Mark

Comment: Thank you for the votes!! Much appreciated. - Mark